# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name throes error = System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in correct format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging

[showa this error then how can i do to solve this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwzpB.png)
I want solve this error immediately its error shows was i'm in creating catch loging into Database
i'm repeating debugging but im failed . tell exactly what happened in this case
anybody know about that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB9x1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help from that little data, it would be great to see which value the user.identity.name has when u try to parse it.

Most likely the error occurs when u try to parse value which is not parsable in to int16 for example a String which contains a name or something similar.

So you got to check if there is actually a number in youre user.identity.name